# how to fix 'shopify.api_version.VersionNotFoundError'

Tags: python, flask, shopify

I am building a simple “Hello World” using Python, Flask and the Shopify Embedded SDK. Following this tutorial----> https://medium.com/@dernis/shopify-embedded-sdk-with-python-flask-6af197e88c63.

After doing all the work when I go to the link ' https://localhost:5000/shopify/install?shop=khawaja-kaleem-com.myshopify.com '   to install the application to test store it gives me this error. Need to fix it.

```
shopify.api_version.VersionNotFoundError.

TRACEBACK (MOST RECENT CALL LAST)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\92344\Downloads\HelloShopify-master\helloshopify\shopify_bp\views.py", line 36, in install
session = shopify.Session(shop_url)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shopify\session.py", line 47, in __init__
self.version = ApiVersion.coerce_to_version(version)
File "C:\Users\92344\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shopify\api_version.py", line 18, in coerce_to_version
raise VersionNotFoundError
shopify.api_version.VersionNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 2):

The ShopifyAPI package specifies the allowed versions in the 'shopify/api_version.py' file. In my case the Shopify platform latest API version is '2022-10' but the latest version allowed by the ShopifyAPI package is '2022-07'.

It seems that the ShopifyAPI package is not always updated quickly after the release of a new API version on the Shopify platform. Try aligning the API version to one of the versions allowed to work around this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the API version you wish to use. Set the version before you make any calls. 2020-10 is the default for now.

See the documentation, it explains everything to you.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/versioning

Comment: i am specifying the API version 2019-04 but i don't know why it is giving this API Version error

Comment: Probably because you are providing the version incorrectly?

Comment: it is the version which i specify on shopify while creating app and also in api_version.py file.

Comment: @AmmarSiddiqui I am facing the same error. Were you able to find a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I found a new way to add version that python sdk did not include.

```
from shopify import ApiVersion, Release
ApiVersion.define_version(Release("2023-07"))
```

Here is the source code, if you are interested in shopify api sdk.

```
@classmethod
    def define_version(cls, version):
        cls.versions[version.name] = version
        return version

    @classmethod
    def define_known_versions(cls):
        cls.define_version(Unstable())
        cls.define_version(Release("2021-10"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-01"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-04"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-07"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2022-10"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2023-01"))
        cls.define_version(Release("2023-04"))
```

so, we just need to add a new version by calling the method: `define_version`.
By the way,the sdk version I am using is: `ShopifyAPI==12.3.0`.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer saved me. I am using ShopifyAPI==10.0.0